# Does a developer requires a farm admin access?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

To connect to the SP 2010 farm from Visual Studio 2013, does a developer requires a Farm admin access?

Develop gets the below error when he tries to connect. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a developer requires farm admin access in order to develop Farm/Sandbox solutions. And of course, SharePoint must be installed locally on their development machine.

Comment: So, only by farm admin access the error will be resolved?

Comment: Yes.  The developer needs to be able to deploy and retract farm solutions and that requires farm admin privileges and local server access.